# Values in model are null or empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEsf(EsfLotDetailsModel model)
{
   ...
}
```

I have two properties in this model.  One is a database POCO object and the other is a list.  In the GET equivalent of this method, these values were all populated correctly, but on post these get set to null (the POCO) and empty (the list).

Why might this be?

My view is here

```
@using UI.Helpers

@model UI.Areas.Admin.Models.EsfLotDetailsModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Forward Lot";

}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/AdminDesignTheme/js/wl_Date.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/AdminDesignTheme/js/wl_Time.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.mousewheel.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@{
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var options = {
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
                };
                $('#Starts').wl_Date(options);
                $('#Ends').wl_Date(options);
                $('#startTime').wl_Time();
                $('#endTime').wl_Time();
            });
        </script>
}

<p>@Html.ActionLink("Back to Item List", "Index","Inventory")</p>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please correct the errors and try again.")
@using (Html.BeginForm(new {model = @Model})) {

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Auction.InventoryReference)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Auction.Title)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Auction.Description)
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <label>ESF Lot Information</label>            

        <section>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Auction.Title)
            <div> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Auction.Title) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.Title)    </div>   
        </section>

        <section>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Auction.Description)
             <div> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Auction.Description) 
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.Description)     </div>  
        </section>

        @if (HttpContextHelper.IsUserAdmin())
        {<section>
             <label for="IsFeatured">Is Featured <i>(displayed in homepage)</i></label>
             <div> @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Auction.IsFeatured) 
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.IsFeatured)     </div>  
        </section>
        }
        else
        {
            <section>
             <label for="IsFeatured">Is Featured <i>(displayed in homepage)</i></label>
             <div> @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Auction.IsFeatured, new { disabled = "disabled" }) (Contact Admin to make this a featured lot) 
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.IsFeatured)     </div>  
            </section>

        }

        @if (HttpContextHelper.IsUserAdmin())
        {<section>
             @Html.Label("VAT Applicable")
             <div> @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Auction.VatApplicable) 
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.VatApplicable)     </div>  
        </section>
        }
        else
        {
            <section>
             @Html.Label("VAT Applicable")
             <div> @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Auction.VatApplicable, new { disabled = "disabled" }) (Contact Admin if it is not VATable) 
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.VatApplicable)     </div>  
            </section>

        }

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <label>Date and Time</label>

        <section>
             <label>Starts <em>(dd/mm/yy hh:mm)</em></label>
             <div> <input type="text" class="date" id="Starts" /> 
                <input type="text" class="time" data-connect="Starts" id="startTime" /> 

             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.Starts)       </div>
        </section>

        <section>
             <label>Ends <em>(dd/mm/yy hh:mm)</em></label>
             <div> <input type="text" class="date" id="Ends" /> 
                   <input type="text" class="time" data-connect="Ends" id="endTime" /> 

             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.Ends)   </div>    
        </section>
        <section>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Auction.IsExtensible)
             <div> @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Auction.IsExtensible) 
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.IsExtensible)     </div>  
        </section>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <label>Bid Options</label>

        <section>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Auction.StartingBid)
             <div> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Auction.StartingBid) 
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.StartingBid)     </div>  
        </section>

        <section>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Auction.Reserve)
             <div> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Auction.Reserve) 
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.Reserve)   </div>    
        </section>

        <section>
             <label>Reserve Visible <em>(Displays as Reserve met or not met)</em></label>
             <div> @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Auction.ReserveVisible) 
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.ReserveVisible)  </div>     
        </section>

        <section>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Auction.IsBidIncrementPercentual)
             <div> @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Auction.IsBidIncrementPercentual) 
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.IsBidIncrementPercentual)     </div>  
        </section>  

        <section>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Auction.BidIncrement)
             <div> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Auction.BidIncrement, new { @Value = 1m })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auction.BidIncrement)        </div>
        </section>              

        <section>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuctionEvents)
             <div> @Html.DropDownList("Auction", Model.AuctionEvents, "Select auction", new { required = "required" }) 
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuctionEvents)       </div>
        </section>

        <section>
            <div><button>Create</button></div>
        </section>        

    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Item List", "Index","Inventory")
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show your view that post to this action?

Comment: And where in this form is list of model? And what is POCO object in model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these options worked.  I put all the values in the POCO object separately in the model instead and removed the POCO object.  No idea why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add FormMethod = FormMethod.Post to your Html.BeginForm()

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller",FormMethod.Post))
{

}
```

Comment: When I did what you wrote in the update then my entire model becomes null.

Answer (score 0):

where is your submit button?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller",FormMethod.Post))
{
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

when you fill in the form, press the submit button, then enter in the [HttpPost] Method and value of Model will be filled.